# android timeout exception on wifi and GPRS

Tags: android, web-services, exception, android-wifi, socket-timeout-exception

Bellow is my code for  calling the service but it gives time out exception

```
    **DefaultHttpClient httpC = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpC.getParams(), false);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpC.getParams(), 15000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpC.getParams(), 15000);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(WebServiceDetails.URL_WS_USER);
    httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);


    try {
        se = new StringEntity(serviceXml,HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        BasicHttpResponse basicHttpResponse =   (BasicHttpResponse)httpC.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = basicHttpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        inputStream = responseEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream),1024*5);
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Response from service -"+total.toString());
        xmlContent=total.toString();
        System.out.println(" status Line = "+basicHttpResponse.getStatusLine());


    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}**
```

it is working on emulator but not on actual device please suggest  any tutorial or example if it is wrong.......

thanksx...

Answer (score 0):

Your real device might be experiencing slow Internet connection speed over mobile network.

To overcome Time-Out issue, I would suggest you to simply increase the time-out duration in order to buy some more time for your web sockets to complete their actions. For example:

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpC.getParams(), 40000); //40 seconds
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpC.getParams(), 40000);         //40 seconds
```

Comment: please have a look  i did it as 

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpC.getParams(), 75000); 
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpC.getParams(), 75000);


but still the problem is there ....